# How to log HTTP errors in java

Tags: java, log4j

I am working on Spring 3. I am going to integrate Log4j in my Application,
Can I log the HTTP error like 404, 505 etc in my log file, because that errors I am redirecting to error-page from web.xml file using  tag.

Comment: I think you may not even need to log it. Most likely, your web server / app server already includes an error log for that kind of HTTP errors. I'd recommend you to read your server logging configuration instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to make a very detailed logging with Spring MVC.

The easiest way is to log it in your error page view file if it is a jsp but you probably cannot do very much detailed logging without pre-handling the exception in Spring controller.

This [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/) is very useful for learning how to properly handle exception from both error-page and from your controller itself. It should give you some idea of what to do.

Comment: If you get a 500, though, without even making it to Spring, then it won't be logged. That's why I suggested basing on the server instead of the framework.

Comment: @VicentePlata I think you can still handle the 500 error series using error-page in web.xml.

Comment: @gigadot Thanks for instant replay, I followed all instructions as given in Tutorial but it shows blank page with error message, can I put Layouts for this page...?

Comment: @VicentePlata Hi, can i put layouts in error page which is redirected using <error-page> tag in web.xml?

Comment: @VicentePlata I am not sure what was wrong because you have given me insufficient information